# FUSE problem launching app in linux with java

Tags: java, multithreading, launcher, fuse, appimage

Hi i'm tring to launch software from java in linux, but i recive this error for appimage:
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option.
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE
for more information

this is the code:

```
public void execAltern(){
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        String exec = "";
        exec = DefaultLaunchExec.defaultLaunch.get(app.getExecProgram())+ app.getExecPath();
        
        processBuilder.command("/bin/bash","-c",exec); // exec is the path of the file 
        System.out.println("\n"+processBuilder.command());
        
        try {

        process = processBuilder.inheritIO().start();
                
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
                        System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
    }
        
        DefaultLaunchExec.appRunning.remove(this);
    }
```

Comment: You provably need to install `libfuse.so.2` for AppImage to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `libfuse2`. Try the following command:
`sudo apt install libfuse2`

For more information, refer to https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/troubleshooting/fuse.html